# Do - while goes into an infinite loop

Tags: java, loops, try-catch, infinite-loop, do-while

Im trying to add an input validation to this menu. When the user enters eg: 'a' or any input that is not a integer and with the given range, it must execute the catch block and loop again to prompt the user to enter again but instead it keeps looping infinitely after taking the input once.  So it goes from executing the menu and just skipping over the input part and executes the catch block.

Edit: it goes into infinite loop if i input anything that is not an integer.

```
Scanner sc = new    Scanner(System.in);

int x = 1;

do{

try

{

System.out.println("Select option ");

System.out.println("1) Circle ");

System.out.println("2) Rectangle ");

System.out.println("3) Triangle ");

System.out.println("4) Exit ");

x = sc.nextInt();

}

catch(Exception e)

{

System.out.print("Invalid data");

}

}while(x<1 || x>4);
```

Comment: `4` is exit, so should it be `>= 4`? Also `nextInt` won't clear the dangling new line character while is still stuck in the buffer (which is the primary cause of your issue) - you should use `nextLine` and then parse the result to an `int`

Comment: Hi, im pretty new at this. Can you tell me how i will be able to parse it?

Comment: Can I somehow CLEAR the input once it executes the catch block? Will that work? Is there a method or something to clear inputs?

Comment: Personally, I'd use `sc.nextLine();` which will return a `String` and then use `Integer.parseInt(valueFromScanner)` to parse the result

Comment: I did  try
          {
            System.out.print("Enter");
            x = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            Integer.parseInt(x);       and it gives me the following error                                                    
     Main.java:17: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());` - although, I'd prefer to assign the result of `nextLine` to a variable, because then I can more easily debug it if I need to

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are not flushing the buffer when the Scanner gets a character/string instead of an int. In addition, your loop will terminate if a character/string is read in on the first iteration since your loop condition will return false with x set initially to 1. You can fix this by setting it to -1 instead. Moreover, instead of using a try catch block, you can use the hasNextInt() method to check if the user is typing in an int or not.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int x = -1;
do {
    System.out.println("Select option ");   
    System.out.println("1) Circle ");
    System.out.println("2) Rectangle ");
    System.out.println("3) Triangle ");
    System.out.println("4) Exit ");

    if (sc.hasNextInt())
    {
        x = sc.nextInt();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");

        // Flush the buffer
        sc.nextLine();
    }
} while (x < 1 || x > 4);

sc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

sc.nextLine();

next

x = sc.nextInt();