# How do I write an "If/else Statement" to condicionate the answer for the user?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am having trouble writing an if/else statement that conditionate the answer of the user.
I am asking the user to enter a number between 1 and 8, if the user enters a number between that range the answer will be storage on a variable, if the answer it is outside the range the program will say something like: "Invalid position."
Something like this:

```
System.out.println("Choose a number (Between 1 to 8)");
if(---------------){
ubNum = input.nextInt();
}else{
System.out.println("Enter a valid number please");
}
```

What do I need to put in the if statement to accomplish it?

Comment: Start by moving `ubNum = input.nextInt()` up before the `if` statement, so you can actually check the value of `ubNum`.

Comment: Did you see this question just an hour ago ? :)   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014004/do-while-goes-into-an-infinite-loop

Comment: I was thinking of that, thanks. Regarding the if statement, how could I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do - while goes into an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014004/do-while-goes-into-an-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are including 1 and 8 number also in your range, then here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Choose a number (Between 1 to 8)");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = sc.nextInt();
        if (a >= 1 && a <= 8)
            System.out.println("No. is valid");
        else
            System.out.println("Enter a valid number please");
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

If the value entered by user is in the given range then that value will be stored in the integer variable `res` and using this you can perform any further calculations on the  value stored in variable `res`.

If the number entered by user is not in the given range then default value(i.e 0) will be printed along with the message `"Enter a valid number please"`.

```
int res = 0;
int a = sc.nextInt();
        if (a >= 1 && a <= 8)
          res=a;
 else
            System.out.println("Enter a valid number please");
              System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: @Kevin Nathaniel Tiscareno now have you got what to write in if statement to accomplish your task??

Comment: When the user enters a number between the range I only want to store the information without giving feedback. How could I do this?

Comment: @Kevin Nathaniel Tiscareno I have editted my answer according to your need, is now your query resolved??